# Can ptrace read/write data from a multithreaded process given that one and only one thread is stopped?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, ptrace

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) on ptrace is a little bit fuzzy to me.
It says:

> A tracee first needs to be attached to the tracer. Attachment and
>   subsequent commands are per thread: in a multithreaded process, every
>   thread can be individually attached to a (potentially different)
>   tracer, or left not attached and thus not debugged. Therefore,
>   "tracee" always means "(one) thread", never "a (possibly
>   multithreaded) process".

Also:

> In the following requests, pid specifies the thread ID of the tracee
>   to be acted on. For requests other than PTRACE_ATTACH, PTRACE_SEIZE,
>   PTRACE_INTERRUPT and PTRACE_KILL, the tracee must be stopped.

So, if we have a multithreaded process and we attach to a single thread with PTRACE_SEIZE and stop it with PTRACE_INTERRUPT, will we able to read/write the entire process's global data with PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, PTRACE_PEEKDATA, PTRACE_POKETEXT or PTRACE_POKEDATA?

Secondary question:
If the answer to the main question is yes, why is it needed for a thread to be stopped? I was thinking that the stop is needed for achieving some sort of locking mechanism, but if a single thread is stopped, then the other ones can write into the memory that ptrace is trying to read/write freely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read the global memory, but the result may be inconsistent if there are running threads modifying the memory concurrently. Moreover, the thread *context* (registers and flags) can only be obtained for traced, stopped threads.